# Why is my favicon not working on server but is working locally?

Tags: html, favicon, server

New to web dev.  I have a favicon that works locally but doesn't want to behave on server.  The following is my favicon tag in the head tag:

`<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="../favicon/microphone-icon-192783/microphone-icon-16-192783.ico"/>`

Am I missing something for the server?

Comment: what server technology? Where is your favicon?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just upload the favicon to your root directory and give it the name "favicon.ico". By putting it in your root directory, you'll have a default favicon for all the pages in your domain.

Depending on the browser you use, you can add the following two lines into the head section of your pages.

```
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"> 
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

Comment: I have determined this is the answer; actually the machine did

Comment: You only need the `rel="shortcut icon"` version, and then only if you want to support IE <=8. If you only care about IE9 and above then only use `rel="icon"` (the standard everyone else follows). All other browsers properly treat `rel` as a space delimited list and `"shortcut icon"` is explicitly allowed anyway. All that being said, be careful with the above code - it's **relative to the current path**, e.g. in `mysite.com/path/page.html` it would refer to `mysite.com/page/favicon.ico`. Also, if your `favicon.ico` is in the root - there's no reason to have the tags at all.

Comment: Thanks!!! ```<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"> ``` helps.

Comment: this is funny 
html link tags didn't add value just restart the browser

Answer (score 18):

Old question but for anyone who experienced the same issue as me..

Spent about an hour trying to figure out why i was experiencing the same problem. Clearing history, updating code didnt work.

Restarted chrome browser and worked straight away ahah

Answer (score 2):

Make an PNG file and set it as the favicon in an index.html page so the cache is overwritten:
`<html><head><link rel='icon' type='image/png' href='favicon.png' /></head></html>`

It works.

Answer (score 0):

Try uploading the icon somewhere on the web, and link it to that image url. I remember having issues with accessing a background-image on local machine, but if I was trying to link it from the web, I had no problems. I think [this](http://www.iconj.com/favicon_hosting.php) should do the trick. Didn't use it though.

Answer (score 0):

You could try removing the `../` like this.

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon/microphone-icon-192783/microphone-icon-16-192783.ico"/>
```

but could we have the file path according to the server root if this doesnt soleve it? its easier to find a solution that way :)

Comment: I don't think that will solve the problem. By putting the `../` he will be going back a folder, to the folder parent to the folder where his file with the link is. Without the `../`, the search will  be performed only in the folder the file with the `<link>` is.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `<link href="/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon">`, where '/' stands for absolute root path... (root direcory)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the folder having the icon image on the server has the permissions set to **0755**.

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="icon" href="./favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"> 
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="./favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

If this still won't update the favicon on the webpage, **RESTART THE BROWSER**